# Magento Range Validator

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to create Magento Range Validation using Range validator.

I want to give range like ( 0 (free)  or >= € 0,99).

Please Any body help me to figure out this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Got The Solutions to add custom validation in Magento.

The above question Solutions is

```
<script>
Validation.add('range-check','<?php echo __('Please enter valid Range.'); ?>',function(value){
    if(value == null || value<0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(!(value>0 && value <1))
    {
        return true;
    }
  });
</script>
```